# how does uninstall a program in "program and features" work?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

while uninstalling one msi package through control panel. In task bar i notice that the msiexec.exe with commandLine \x was not getting called but still the msi package got uninstalled. In registry where that particular software was stored in that they have provided uninstallstring in which something like this is given "MsiExec.exe /X{2012098D-EEE9-4769-8DD3-B038050854D4}".

so there are other way through which it does uninstall the software without calling Msiexec.exe??

and if it does then how ??
can someone please enlighten me on this

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Installer products the UninstallString in the registry is not used. Windows simply calls the API to do the uninstall. Yes, sometimes that's a pain if you'd like to customize the uninstall to do something different, but that's the way it works.

Comment: thanks @PhilDW so the UninstallString means nothing for windows Installer. But through ProcMon i notice that while uninstalling the msi package through control panel msiexec.exe was getting called and in the task bar nothing strange was happening. So might be they are internally calling msiexec.exe? or some API .. and if it is API then which API?

Comment: Correct. This is the API being called: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370315(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: PS- It is technically possible to override this behavior by using the ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT property and then authoring the Uninstall key entry yourself.  But this can introduce more problems then it solves and it's generally best to conform to Windows Installer best practices and built-in behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The legacy way of adding a program to the ARP (Add/Remove Programs control panel) is to specify the uninstaller's command string (e.g. `c:\app\uninstall.exe`) in either of the following registry keys:

```
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

OR

```
KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

And the path to the uninstaller is specified by the "UninstallString" value for each subkey

Installer's that do not use MSI use exactly this technique to show up in ARP to suppor uninstall.

More details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

msiexec.exe is the general process used for install / uninstall task. It takes as an argument the specific program id / class id which is of the form GUID - the long hex string you posted.

Even if you don't see it executing with /x switch, it is silently passed this string when you choose to uninstall something right from control panel - the result of which is uninstallation.